# Почему не переключает?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Почему когда я вставляю код с выбором option в select и вывод данные в другом блоке, здесь всё работает. А когда вставляю на сайте, выбивается ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at HTMLSelectElement.but..onclick

Сcылка на страницу: [url](http://beautyhub.pro/wishlist)

**Для того чтоб там появились товары, нужно нажать на сердечки.**

В первые с таким сталкиваюсь....

```js
var but = document.querySelectorAll('.product_item .variant_select');

for (var b in but)
    but[b].onclick = function(){
    var father = this.parentNode;
    var a = father.querySelector(`[value="${this.value}"]`).getAttribute('for');
    
    father.querySelector('.weight_product').innerHTML = `Вес брутто*: ${a} kg`;
};
```

```html
<div class="product_item">
<select name="variant" class="fn_variant variant_select  " id="myselect">
  <option for="1.24" value="295" data-price="36,83" data-stock="50" selected="selected">1kg</option>
  <option for="0.45" value="296" data-price="15,89" data-stock="50">300g</option>
</select>
  
  <div class="weight_product">Вес брутто*: 5.24 kg</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="product_item">
<select name="variant" class="fn_variant variant_select  " id="myselect">
  <option for="1.24" value="267" data-price="38,26" data-stock="50" selected="selected">1kg</option>
  <option for="0.4" value="268" data-price="18,30" data-stock="50" data-cprice="21,00">250g</option>
</select>
  
  <div class="weight_product">Вес брутто*: 1.24 kg</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Делать это надо бы на `onchange` у <select>. 2. Где на сайте ошибка? Вы убрали? Зачем тогда сюда ссылку давать?

Comment: К проблеме это не относится, но у вас куча объектов на странице с одинаковыми id, что как бы не хорошо.

Comment: Ничего не убирал https://yadi.sk/i/nOMW7dJRPDqorQ

Comment: Не знаю что там у вас на диске, но можно было просто пару слов написать. Я уже понял что они не везде есть. В общем-то, не работает на сайте - дебажить надо на сайте, а не отдельно код вырезать. Мне дебаггер показывает и father и a == undefined.

Comment: Вы дебажить или логировать умеете? Скорее всего, у вас father -- совсем не то, что вы ожидаете.

Comment: Вот смотрите https://yadi.sk/i/RT5k9zkqqK5Psw
Надо вставить в своём блоке, https://yadi.sk/i/aQcUhOlyfQ0Zfg